# Rename property names from WCF service generated model

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm currently consuming a legacy WCF service that does not conform to the naming standards from the app in development. Now when developing against a REST service, where I create the models on my own it is really easy to rename a property like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

But with the WCF service it generates the model, and I don't want to edit a generated file as all my changes would be lost when someone/-thing triggers the code generation again. So how could I achieve the same goal when consuming a WCF service?

Comment: Is not auto-generating the code in visual studio and doing it via [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx) and adding the .cs file it creates (after you tweak it) be acceptable?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks I'll check it out. I'm quite new to the subject WCF so I thought there might be a really trivial solution to my problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> How about adapter pattern?
> ```

this would allow you to play with your class object myClass in your application, whereas when it is being passed on to the service you can have exposedClaSs which is auto generated.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the generated code you'll see that the DataContract classes are partial.

You could add a file to the project with the same partial class definition and make wrapper properties with the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using the proxy generator is a total waste of time: what you want to do is manage your classes by hand and let something else deal with the underlying implementation details in a way that does no impact you and is resilient to change. The way we do this on our current project is to use the castle dynamic proxy to dispatch the calls to the channel factory.

We've done something like this http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/10/13/dynamic-proxy-for-wcf-with-castle-dynamicproxy/ and have found it to work very well.